# NSTableView doesn't update values on edit

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have a cell-based NSTableView in my app, bound to an array of [String, NSNumber]. I have turned on editing in IB and added a delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue anObject: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row rowIndex: Int) {
    guard var d = deck?.geometryCards[rowIndex].data else { return }
    guard let i = tableColumn?.identifier where i.length > 0 else { return }
    let key = i.substring(0, length:(i.length - "Column".length))

    print("before setting " + String(d[key]))

    if key[0] == "F" {
        d[key] = NSNumber(double: Double((anObject as? String)!)!)
    } else if key[0] == "I" {
        d[key] = NSNumber(int: Int32((anObject as? String)!)!)
    }

    print("after setting " + String(d[key]))
}
```

When I click on the cell and change its value, I see...

```
before setting Optional(-1.1562)
after setting Optional(5.5)
```

Excellent! The only problem is the value in the NSTableView doesn't change, it returns to 1.1562. And if I do the edit again, I get...

```
before setting Optional(-1.1562)
after setting Optional(5.5)
```

I am missing something in the chain of events, the value is going into the dict but then getting reset somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Swift dictionaries are value types.  When you assign a dictionary to another variable, you get a copy. Your variable `d` is a copy of the dictionary, not the original one.  So you are modifying the copy, but not the original dictionary.

If the cards in your `geometryCards` are objects and not structs, this should work:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue anObject: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row rowIndex: Int) {
    guard let c = deck?.geometryCards[rowIndex] else { return }
    guard let i = tableColumn?.identifier where i.length > 0 else { return }
    let key = i.substring(0, length:(i.length - "Column".length))

    print("before setting " + String(c.data[key]))

    if key[0] == "F" {
        c.data[key] = NSNumber(double: Double((anObject as? String)!)!)
    } else if key[0] == "I" {
        c.data[key] = NSNumber(int: Int32((anObject as? String)!)!)
    }

    print("after setting " + String(c.data[key]))
}
```

Comment: Also, checking for "F" vs. "I" isn't necessary.  `c.data[key] = Double(anObject as? String ?? "") ?? 0` should give you the expected results without the possibility of crashing.

Comment: Works like a champ. I'm not sure I'm ever going to get the value type thing correct. Syntax that seems very natural to me simply doesn't work when you do "obvious" things.